# Android source code debugging in Eclipse - Location service

Tags: android, android-service, android-source

I am trying to map the flow of function calls in android - how the control flows when an API is called by the app. My first case study is location service.

While debugging, the control never reaches to LocalationManagerService.java

- My LocationDemo app calls (LocationManager)requestLocationUpdates
- It can be traced to LocationManager.java which in turn calls requestLocationUpdates defined in ILocationManager (aidl file)
- ILocationManager is implemented in LocationManagerService.java.
  But Eclipse complains that `ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.requestLocationUpdates(...) source not found`

Is it possible to link LocationManager <-> ILocationManager <-> LocationManagerService?
If not how can I debug the code in LocationManagerService?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is LocationManagerService is one of the framework services that runs inside system_server application.
To step through its code, please check [Debugging Android Framework services](http://apienthusiast.blogspot.com/2014/06/debugging-android-java-framework.html).